# Is there a way to test whether a regex_t instance was successfully compiled?

Tags: c, regex

Is there a getter for a `regex_t` instance that reveals whether it's been successfully compiled? Or is the only way to keep track of the return-value from `regcomp()`?

E.g. in the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <regex.h>

static const char* str[] = { "foo", "bar" };

int main()
{
  regex_t r[(sizeof str)/(sizeof *str)];
  size_t i = 0;

  for ( ; i < (sizeof r)/(sizeof *r); ++i ) { regcomp( &r[i], str[i], 0 ); }

  for ( i = 0; i < (sizeof r)/(sizeof *r); ++i ) { regfree( &r[i] ); }

  return 0;
}
```

is `regfree()` safe to call against `regex_t` instances for which `regcomp()` failed? If not, can I test whether a `regex_t` instance was successfully compiled, or do I need to keep track of all the `regcomp()` return-values to know which `regex_t`s are safe to free?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't think so, unless some particular system provides something special.  As far as [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/regcomp.html) is concerned, `regex_t` is meant to be opaque to the user, and there aren't any standard functions dealing with `regex_t` besides `regcomp`, `regexec`, `regerror`, `regfree`.  Also, according to POSIX, if `regcomp` fails, the contents of `preg` are undefined.

So you'll have to keep track of it yourself.

Comment: The man-page on `regfree()` did not say whether or not it's safe to call with uncompiled `regex_t` instances. That being the case, it's probably best to assume that it _is not_ safe to call with uncompiled `regex_t` instances, right? (Experimentally, it appears to do no harm, but under the circumstances, I'm inclined to think that might be undefined behavior)

Comment: @StoneThrow: From my link: "If the preg argument to regexec() or regfree() is not a compiled regular expression returned by regcomp(), the result is undefined."  The contents of `preg` after a failed `regcomp` are undefined, so you certainly can't be sure it's a compiled regular expression.